# Arduino Mega2560 and Eclipse pin error and communicaton

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, arduino, eclipse-cdt, avr

I can not connect the arduino mega 2560 to my eclipse projects. I have Avr-plugin set.
It works with Uno. I can not read the MCU signature.I know that the clock frequency is 16Mhz and I set the port to \.\COMx. I use brate 115200 or 57600 and I have use also everything, and for programmer i use most Arduino programmer that works with Uno and i have tried stk500(all of them). It can not connect either to an arduino Mega2560 R3 and R2.
I have also another problem with the pins. Everytime I try to add the pin_arduino.h for mega i get the error that you can see at the picture i have attached. The members of the array that does not get any error are the same that the arduino Uno has.

Is there and solution to my problems?

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you imported the MEGA core library? See "Creating the ArduinoCore Library" [here](http://horrorcoding.altervista.org/arduino-development-with-eclipse-a-step-by-step-tutorial-to-the-basic-setup/).

Comment: i found the solution for the pins.i just have to set the library to atmega and 16Mhz in order to understand the correct pin_out.But the communication from the projects still does not work.Any idea?I know the tutorial, i have read it many times and i think there is no mega core library there are different manage configurations. Thank you anyway

Comment: Have you tried using avrdude from the command line to see if you can connect? It sounds like the answer should be yes and that eclipse just isn't understanding what response avrdude is giving it but I just want to make sure.